# Conditional operators in comments floatval

Tags: javascript, if-statement, knockout.js, operators

I'm trying to make a conditional statement that renders an element depending on the floatval-value inside a property of an observableArray I'm iterating over

When I render the value itself it works:

```html
<span data-bind="text: stinger.points"></span>
```

For each in the observableArray I see the correct value, such as "3.2".

Heres my actual statement, but none of them gets displayed in the computed html:

```html
<!-- ko if: stinger.points  >1.49 && stinger.points <2.49 -->
    <div>1.5 - 2.48</div>       
<!-- /ko -->            
<!-- ko if: stinger.points  >2.49 && stinger.points <3.49 -->
    <div>2.5 - 3.48</div>
<!-- /ko -->    
<!-- ko if: stinger.points  >3.49 && stinger.points <4.49 -->
    <div>3.5 - 4.48</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: stinger.points  >4.49 && stinger.points <5.1 -->
    <div>4.5 - 5</div>      
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: stinger.points  <0.1  -->
    <div >0</div>           
<!-- /ko -->
```

Or I could approach it like this:

```html
<div data-bind="visible: rating.points > 1.2 && rating.points < 3.4">between 1.3 - 3.5</div>
```

However, thats also not working, like above.

What am I doing wrong? How to correct this?

Comment: Is stinger.points a ko.observable?

Comment: no it is a property of a property of a ko.observableArray([])

Answer (score 2):

When you use observable in the expression you have to unwrap it by adding (). Update your code as follow:

```
<!-- ko if: stinger.points()  >1.49 && stinger.points() <2.49 -->
    <div>1.5 - 2.48</div>       
<!-- /ko -->            
<!-- ko if: stinger.points()  >2.49 && stinger.points() <3.49 -->
    <div>2.5 - 3.48</div>
<!-- /ko -->    
<!-- ko if: stinger.points()  >3.49 && stinger.points() <4.49 -->
    <div>3.5 - 4.48</div>
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: stinger.points()  >4.49 && stinger.points() <5.1 -->
    <div>4.5 - 5</div>      
<!-- /ko -->
<!-- ko if: stinger.points()  <0.1  -->
    <div >0</div>           
<!-- /ko -->
```

Comment: Awesome thats it, i´m very new to knockout and a bit confused about this function7object thing thanks a lot

Comment: But you should really move these rules to computeds on the view model